# How to set the DataSource of a DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, wpf-controls

I need to set a table from a database to be the DataSource of a GridGrid in WPF. In Windows Forms the property is called `DataSource` but in WPF no such property exists, so how can i do it?

Comment: You mean "in Windows Forms", not "in C#"... C# is a language, not a UI framework

Comment: I assumed as much as well and went ahead to edit it since C# does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes i mean Windows Forms. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourData}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <!-- The columns here -->
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you prefer to use code-behind rather than a binding, just give a name to the `ListView` and set the `ItemsSource` property in code:

```
listView1.ItemsSource = YourData;
```

You can also use the `ItemsSource` property with other list controls (`DataGrid`, `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, etc), since it is defined in the `ItemsControl` base class.

---

EDIT: if the data source is a `DataTable`, you can't assign it directly to `ItemsSource` because it doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, but you can do it through a binding:

```
listView1.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = YourData });
```

Comment: But "YourData" how you say is an have to be an object? Because if i do it like in Windows Forms, with a Datatable, it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, yes, DataTable is a special case... see the edit in my answer

Comment: But i have another problem, if i want to bind data to the DataGrid, but if i already have columns defined in the DataGrid, how can i put the binding Data in the existing columns?

Comment: I need for example to set something as a DataSource of a DataGrid (and i already have achieved that), but imagine that i already have columns (as TextBox or/and ComboBox) in the DataGrid. I can put the Data successfully in the cells of the columns as TextBox by defining the 'Binding' Property, but to put the data in the columns as ComboBox i don't understand how i can do it.

Comment: You can use a DataGridComboBoxColumn. I can't really give you a detailed explanation in the comments, have a look at the example in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

This is simple an example:

**XAML part** :

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Width="866" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

**C# part** :

... [code to read and fill your table ] ...

```
da.Fill(myDataTable);
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

And now your DataGrid will be filled with your DataTable

Answer (score 2):

The `GridView` is a view and not a standalone control as far as i know, you would normally use it as the view of a `ListView`. In WPF the property for data population is called `ItemsSource`, you probably want to either use a `ListView` or `DataGrid` to display your data that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below both ways to bind the datatable to datagrid in WPF.

```
 datagrid.ItemSource = mydt.DefaultView();

 datagrid.DataContext = mydt.DefaultView();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this code, its work load from csv
in `.xaml`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source=ClusterList}"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ClusterNumber" Binding="{Binding ClusterNumber}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ServerName" Binding="{Binding ServerName}"/>
/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

then I have `c#` code of view

```cs
public DiscoveryView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ClusterList = new ObservableCollection<ClusterData>();
    LoadDataFromCsv();
    dataGridView1.ItemsSource = ClusterList;}

public class ClusterData
{
    public string ClusterNumber { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<ClusterData> ClusterList { get; set; }

private void LoadDataFromCsv()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("./Configs/clusterlist.csv"))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            ClusterList.Add(new ClusterData
            {
                ClusterNumber = values[0],
                ServerName = values[1]
            });
        }
    }
}
```

maybe this code is for beginners, but it works for me