# get data from dataset

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, dataset, datasource

I've created dataset using `Add new data source`. Then I created `BindingSource bs` and I fill it with data using method GetData(ShoppingMallDataSet is a newly added dataset)

```
void GetData(){
    using(ShoppingMallDataSet smds = new ShoppingMallDataSet())
    {
         using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
         {
              using (var adapter = new   ShoppingMallDataSetTableAdapters.TClientTableAdapter() { Connection = conn })
              {
                  adapter.Fill(smds.TClient);
                  bs.DataSource = smds.TClient;
              }
         }
    } 
}
```

I set value of datagrid datasource `rgv.DataSource = bs` and then call this method GetData(). In debugger bs.DataSource not null and it has data. But gridview has no columns,no data(but datasource at the same time is not null)

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
.....
rgv.DataSource = bs;
GetData();
....... // rgv doesn't have any data but datasource is not null and has the same value as bs
```

Is something is wrong or it's incorrect way to get data?

Comment: If you're simply trying to set the ItemSource of the data grid, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398441/how-to-set-the-datasource-of-a-datagrid-in-wpf

Comment: it's for wpf but I need for winforms

Comment: Make sure that the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the grid view is set to true.

Comment: Try to set `DataMember` property to a table name.

Answer (score 0):

`BindingSource` has two properties:

- **DataSource**: You must assign your dataset to this property
- **DataMember**: You must assign a table name of dataset to this property

You must set `DataMember` in addition to `DataSource`

```
    bs.DataMember = "TClient";
```